# Python Selenium: can't figure out locator for the clickable link element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm using selenium python 3 and have tried but need assistance finding clickable link element xpath.

My last attempt at xpath show 1 of 1 match but still can't pull element:

```
elem_available=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'#')] //parent::td[@class='noSCL']//parent::tr['@']//parent::tbody['@']//parent::table[@class='status-buttons']//parent::div[@id='status-buttons-on-break']")
```

Element
[image]

Comment: _but still can't pull element_ What happens when you try?  Do you get an error message?  Does anything happen at all?

Answer (score 0):

[explicit-waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)-An explicit wait is a code you define to wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code

```
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Available").click()
```

OR

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Available"))).click()
```

Comment: bharatk  - the first didn't find element and second suggestion returns exception: TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @Python_new Share your website link.

Comment: i can't since its only avail after login

Answer (score 0):

To click on element use `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable`.Try the following `xpath`

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='status-buttons-work-offline']//table[@class='status-buttons']//tr//td//a[contains(.,'Available')]"))).click()
```

You need to use following import.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is an [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Available"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#status-buttons-work-offline > table.status-buttons > tr > td a[onclick^='AgentStatusController']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='status-buttons-work-offline']/table[@class='status-buttons']/tr/td//a[starts-with(@onclick, 'AgentStatusController') and contains(.,'Available')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I added the import statements but each suggested option returned TimeoutException

Comment: @bharatk here's element code javascript-formatted in notepad++  :                                                                           
                                          https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UKCmhv7fd0qrbE4nlPVehlMeTWhmNowU