# Error in locating the link for .click( ))

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I would like to seek help from you.
I have a script that gets the data from "https://www.oddsportal.com/".
It's been running fine. However, recently, I found the following error:

```
Element <a href=""> is not clickable at point (398,651) because another element <div class="ot-sdk-row"> obscures it
```

[I have looked at this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56712404/python-selenium-cant-figure-out-locator-for-the-clickable-link-element)

It did not work out.
Below is the code that shows the above error:

```
class SetupEnvironment:

def __init__(self, username=False, password=False, timezone_number=31):
    ''' Accepts username:str, password:str, timezone_number:int as
    parameters '''
    global browser
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True # change to true to see the browser
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r'./geckodriver')
    actions = webdriver.ActionChains(browser)
    browser.set_page_load_timeout(600)
    self.change_timezone(timezone_number)
    if (username and password): self.login(username, password)
    wait_to_scrape(2)

def __set_correct_score(self, element):
    ''' Set the correct score 
    Returns a list of dictionaries of type

    {
        score: str
        bookmakers: list
    }
    '''
    try:
        header = element.find_element_by_class_name('table-header-light')
    except:
        return []

    show_bookmakers = header.find_element_by_tag_name('strong') \
                                    .find_element_by_tag_name('a')
    score = show_bookmakers.text.replace(':', '-')
    odds_count = header.find_element_by_class_name('odds-cnt').text[-1:-1]

    bookmakers = []
    if (odds_count != 0):
        show_bookmakers.click()
       
        bookmakers = self.__get_bookmakers('cs', element)
    else:
        bookmakers.append({
            'bookmarker': 'N/A', 
            'odd': 'N/A' })

    data = { 
        'score': score, 
        'bookmakers': bookmakers 
    }

    wait_to_scrape(1)

    return data
```

I would like to seek your kind help to resolve it.
Please do let me know should you need additional information.

Comment: This means an element is overlapping it. You can either deal with the overlapping element or try driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()',elem).

Answer (score 1):

The error you presenting is clear, your problem is not with locating the element rather than with the problem that the element you are trying to click is overlapped by some other element.
This may be caused by several issues:

1. The element is out of the visible view port. In this case you will have to scroll this element into the view first, then you can click it.
   Scroll the element into the view can be done with command like this:

```py
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.find_element_by_css_selector('your_css_selector'))
```

2. It is possibly that you trying to click the element before the rendering is completed. In this case Expected Conditions explicitly wait may help.

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "the_element_css_locator"))).click()
```

3. Sometimes you have no alternative and will have to use JavaScript click

```py
element = driver.find_element_by_id("myid")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: wow I learned so much just from one answer, thanks

Comment: You are sincerely welcome :)

Comment: @Prophet , Thanks a lot for providing multiple answers. I will try it out. I must admit that I am new to this also.

Comment: Sure, no problem! In case there any anymore questions - please ask. But as a new, separate questions

Comment: It seems the script is running without any error. But, I could not get the output file because it is supposed to save in a CSV file. So I do not know if I put the correct CSS locator. I think this ("the_element_css_locator")) has to be replaced with the CSS locator, Am I right?

Comment: Sure, you should put there your actual locator.

Comment: @Prophet, Thanks. It does not save in a file, I am not sure why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242222/discussion-between-zephyr-and-prophet).